# Starteam - Checking out files for a specific Change Request #

Tags: starteam

I'm using Starteam 2005 and was wondering if it is possible to checkout any files which were checked in for a Change Request #.

For example, CR # 123456 had the following files checked in for it:

fileA.txt - Revision 21

fileB.txt - Revision 199

fileC.txt - Revision 345

fileD.txt - Revision 721

fileE.txt - Revision 444

Since then all the files have been updated multiple times and each has a revision much higher than that.
Can I call STCMD and checkout all files which were checked in for CR 123456 ???

Comment: I've written code in .NET for StarTeam 2006 that gets all the files checked in by a user for a given CR. So you might be able to do something programmatically, but I haven't played with the command line so I'm not sure how you'd do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the *StarTeam SDK* for that,
and write a tool (in Java / Perl / VB / .Net) that will get those file-revisions for you.

Borland introduced *Change-Packets* in later releases of StarTeam,
to allow you to *promote* changes from one view to another, based on the *Packet* they belong to.